# How do I protect celery queues when using the same rabbitmq for dev and production

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using rabbitmq and celery for backend tasks, and I would like to use the same rabbitmq for dev/test but dont want to ever have the case where someone accidentally brings up celery workers for production queues and uses them for dev/test.  How does one protect celery queues from being accessed by any celery worker who also has access to the same rabbitmq backend, if thats even possible.

Answer (score 0):

keep different queue_name_prefix in BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS for development and test.

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'queue_name_prefix':'development/test',
    'wait_time_seconds': 10,
    'polling_interval': 30,
    'visibility_timeout': 3600 * 5
}
```

Comment: Yes but someone may accidentally add the production prefix when testing

Comment: The queue_name_prefix can be passed as hostname (gethostname()) of the system or any other variable which vary with environment. Workers identify tasks from the queue_name_prefix only, queue_name_prefix is used for the very purpose you have asked for. I don't know any other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I have set up a rabbitmq virtual host to which the production rabbitmq user has exclusive access.  The password for the production user is then stored similar to the production django secret key.

```
RABBIT_USER = os.environ.get('TANTALUS_RABBIT_USER', 'guest')
RABBIT_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('TANTALUS_RABBIT_PASSWORD', 'guest')
RABBIT_VHOST = os.environ.get('TANTALUS_RABBIT_VHOST', '')
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://{}:{}@1.2.3.4:5672/{}'.format(RABBIT_USER, 
RABBIT_PASSWORD, RABBIT_VHOST)
```

A new rabbit user can be added with:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user produser prodpassword
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags produser administrator
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost prodvhost
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p prodvhost produser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```